# Prestige Transfer after starting MW3

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, call-of-duty-black-ops, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I realise that I can get prestige tokens in MW3 for having previously prestiged in MW2/BlackOps, but after playing MW3 for a while can I now go back to the earlier games and prestige in them **again** to get more prestige tokens?

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't be possible. On the other hand, you can just spend the same amount of energy on MW3 and prestige there.

Comment: @Bora I'm at level 70 in both games but haven't gone prestige again because I wanted to hang on to the later weapons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You don't get prestige tokens for each prestige rank you have.](http://www.callofduty.com/message/50897)  You get a prestige token from having gone prestige in a previous game (so 2nd prestige in MW2 buys you no more prestige tokens then 10th prestige).

However, if you haven't gone prestige in a previous game (Modern Warfare, MW2, World at War, or Black ops), you can go back and prestige to gain an additional token.

Hope this helps!