# Why Do MW2 Maps Keep Crashing?

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

So I am level 59 in MW2 multiplayer, and am planning on getting MW3 in the near future. I want to be able to prestige before then so I can get the bonuses listed in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35094/prestige-transfer-after-starting-mw3/35100#35100). But whenever I play on any maps other than [Highrise](http://www.mw2blog.com/modern-warfare-2-multiplayer-maps-highrise/), [Querry](http://www.mw2blog.com/modern-warfare-2-multiplayer-maps-quarry/), and [Afghan](http://www.mw2blog.com/modern-warfare-2-multiplayer-maps-afghan/), My xbox crashes and says

```
The disk you have entered is unreadable. 
Please try wiping it with a cloth or cleaning it.
```

My disk is scratched, but I am afraid of fixing it because all of the reviews I have seen of people do this have been good like:`This saved me $60!!!!!`, to `You suck!!!!!!!!!! You ruined my disc`
Obvisously it will take me forever to prestige if I can only play on 3 maps. Is there anyway around this? Also is there any ways to fix it for free that you have used and work?
 Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sounds like your disc has gone bad.  That sucks.

Comment: @GnomeSlice That would suck

Comment: Double check the disk to make sure it isn't scratched. I had a similar problem caused by a ring around the disk. If that's the case, you can either try to repair it yourself or see if a game store offers disk repair.

Comment: @Fluttershy It is scratched, and a local store does do repairs..... I will try that

Comment: @Fluttershy Do you know of any do-it yourself ones that work? all of them on youtube have comments like "This worked so well!!!!" and at the same time "You ruined my disc"

Comment: @OutlawLemur I do not, but someone in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) might be able to help find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most nearby video stores ( now commonly *Family Video* or *GameStop* ) will do disc repairs but it **depends how deep the scratches really are**.

I would assume most replies of `You Suck! You ruined my disc` are that in actuality, a customer unable to come to the terms that their disc has become unrepairable prior to trying to clean it (and now has to bite the bullet of buying a new one or moving on).

I would try a local video rental store or GameStop (if applicable). Ultimately, if these options fail,  buy a new disc or moving on to (in your case) Modern Warfare 3.  I do not think it is worth it to buy a disc cleaning kit if you have already tried the first option.   At some point your recovery efforts may become more expensive then purchasing a new, unscratched game.

Comment: Okay, I have a `GameStop` near me... Thanks for your help!